# Book recommendations on surround sound

Tags: books, surround-sound, 5.1, recommendations, techniques

I'm interested in learning more about surround sound. Can anyone recommend a comprehensive book that will be appropriate for someone who has basic knowledge but wants to get into surround studio, recording, and mixing? Looking for something that covers the basics but then gets in depth.

Thanks!
Joy

Answer (score 3):

this book is a very simple, basic, easy-and-fast-to-read beginners' book on the topic, but after you have a good grasp on the subject I'd move on to the Holman book:
[http://www.amazon.com/Instant-Surround-Sound-Jeffrey-Fisher/dp/1578202469/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1267554314&sr=1-3](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1578202469)

Comment: Hey thanks -- that was the intention to write a fast introduction for the novice (and the video person who needs to understand surround). Then on to Holman ... --Jeffrey P. Fisher

Answer (score 2):

5.1 Surround Sound Up and Running by Holman is the only book I know of on the topic:

[http://www.amazon.com/5-1-Surround-Sound-Up-Running/product-reviews/0240803833/ref=dp_top_cm_cr_acr_txt?ie=UTF8&showViewpoints=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0240803833)

Comment: Yeah, this book seems like it covers it all. It's pretty extensive. I had a quick look at it a while back. 

Answer (score 2):

Another could be this one: [http://www.amazon.com/Tools-Surround-Sound-Mixing-Book/dp/087930832X/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1267506145&sr=1-4](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/087930832X)

Is more focused on Mixing, but has great general concepts on surround sound.

Answer (score 2):

Another book worth considering is Spatial Audio by Francis Rumsey:

[http://www.amazon.co.uk/Spatial-Audio-Technology-Francis-Rumsey/dp/0240516230](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0240516230)

Comment: my old uni lecturer! ;-)